# Есть ли программы выводящие 3д массив в кубическую графику (как майнкрафт)?

Tags: python, c#, c++, 3d

Есть ли программы или библиотеки желательно на python или c# или cpp, которые на основании 3д массива делают графику из кубов?

Comment: CloudCompare посмотрите

Comment: Есть, конечно...